# (harmonic) one form (independent of choice of chart)

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, riemann-surfaces

For $S$ a Riemann surface, on a chart $U$ with local coordinate $z = x+iy,$ define $$w = df = f_x dx + f_ydy$$ on $U$ where $f$ is a $C^2-$harmonic function ($f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0$; ($(f_{xx} + f_{yy}) dx \wedge dy = 0$ with all continuous second partial derivatives).

I want to verify that for two charts $U, V$ on $S$ with $U \cap V \neq \phi$, and $w = df$ on $U$ and $w = dg$ on $V$, $$w \ \mbox{is well-defined on} \ U \cap V.$$

That is, on $U$ wtih local coordinate $z = x+iy$, $$w = f_x dx + f_y dy$$ and on $V$ with local coordinate $\omega = s+it,$ $$w = g_s ds + g_t dt,$$ then I would like to show that $$g_s = \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} f_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}f_y \ \mbox{and} \ g_t = \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} f_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}f_y$$ on $U \cap V.$

We know only that $$f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0 = g_{ss} + g_{tt}.$$

$\textbf{Attempt}$ Let $$A = \frac{\partial x}{\partial s} f_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial s}f_y, B=\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} f_x + \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}f_y.$$

Then I compute $\frac{\partial}{\partial s} A+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}B$ and try to use the fact that $$f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 0$$ and hope it leads me to some relation that I want. It is quite long and the results do not closed to what I want with many extra terms. I am not sure now how should I proceed. Any help please !!

Comment: To say that the harmonicity is given by the usual $\Bbb R^2$ Laplacian, you need to know something more about these charts. But your question does not make much sense to me. You seem to be saying that a harmonic $1$-form ($w$ closed and $\star w$ closed) is unique, and that's certainly false for general Riemann surfaces. You'd better check carefully what's going on here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use the following on $U\cap V$
$$\begin{align}
g_t&= w(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})\\  
&=(f_xdx+f_ydy)(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})\\
&=f_xdx(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})+f_ydy(\frac{\partial}{\partial t})\\
&=f_x(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t})+f_y(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t})
\end{align}$$
Now you need to show that the expression of $w$ is the same for both charts as follows
$$\begin{align}w&=f_x dx+f_y dy\\
&=f_x(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}ds)+f_y(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}dt+\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}ds)\\
&=(......)dt+(......)ds\\
&=g_t dt+g_s ds
\end{align}$$

Comment: I think this is what I need to prove. I am not sure why can I use it ?